USB visible in disks but unable to format ; all options disabled
Ubuntu 23.10.1
having a USB flash drive which is unrecognizable in windows and mac and now when plugged in Ubuntu, it is only visible in disks utility but there is no option enabled to format. see attached screenshot.

edit Mount options open below window

fdisk -l does not show this device

fdisk /dev/sda gives below output

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No medium found
how can we partition and format the USB in ubuntu ?

Looks like a dead device. No magic here.

Yup, sorry to say but as mikewhatever said it looks like it's dead; when you can list the interface e.g. in lsusb but you can't see any device in lsblk it's usually dead. You may try and unbend it in case it's bent, clean the contacts (which almost never helps) and, if skilled enough, to reflow the traces from the usb connector to the PCB, but other than that, there's no magic you could do from within the system.
